# Can I dynamically check current radiobutton array based on a specific arrayname?

Tags: html, jquery

Let's say I have three columns with a arraybutton array:

**html**

```
<input type="radio" name="clude[1]">Include
<input type="radio" name="clude[1]">Exclude

<input type="radio" name="clude[2]">Include
<input type="radio" name="clude[2]">Exclude

<input type="radio" name="clude[3]">Include
<input type="radio" name="clude[3]">Exclude
```

I have som html-code like this (that does work):

**jQuery:**

```
$("div input[name='clude[1]']").live( "click", function() {
    alert('radio column1');
  });

$("div input[name='clude[2]']").live( "click", function() {
    alert('radio column2');
  });

$("div input[name='clude[3]']").live( "click", function() {
    alert('radio column3');
  });
```

This works if I know that the columns are always 3. But number of columns are generated dynamically based on a csv-file and sometimes it is two columns but sometimes it could be for example 14 columns.

I would love to have something like this:

```
//Go through all columns (all columns has a clude[] element with first index 1!)  
$("div input[name='clude[]']").map(function(n,i){
    $("div input[name='clude[" + (i+1) + "]']").live( "click", function() {
      alert(i);
    });      
  });
```

(But this code does not work because the radiobuttons are generated dynamically, so nothing happens with this last map etc. (because they don't exist when jquery loads with this code))

I hope you understand what I mean!
**Is there any way of doing this?**

Comment: jQuery [.live()](https://api.jquery.com/live/) has been removed super long ago... (january 2013)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette - true. I'm using Wordpress jquery and it works in my development environment :-) But thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Then I would suggest you to ALWAYS mention that in your future questions... Because it is not always obvious and chances are that you will have some non-working answers due to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` attribute can make a huge benefit in this case .. And by using `$("input[name^='clude['")` selector to make only one `click` event for all the inputs

```js
$("input[name^='clude['").on( "click", function() {
  console.log('radio' + $(this).data('num'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="clude[1]" data-num="1">Include
<input type="radio" name="clude[1]" data-num="1">Exclude

<input type="radio" name="clude[2]" data-num="2">Include
<input type="radio" name="clude[2]" data-num="2">Exclude

<input type="radio" name="clude[3]" data-num="3">Include
<input type="radio" name="clude[3]" data-num="3">Exclude
```

Comment: wow! Thanks a lot! Really neat solution!  I suppose name^ tells that it's the start of the name? (clude[)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Yes, exactly `^` means starts with , `*` means contains , `$` means ends with

Comment: Ok thanks for this! There's no reason not accepting this answer :-)

Comment: You're totally welcome @bestprogrammerintheworld .. have a nice day :-)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld my answer doesn't need the `data` attribute if you interested in doing it easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can add delegated listener like this:

```
$('body').on('click', 'div input[name^="clude"]', function(){
  var $this=$(this),
    thisName = $this.attr('name'),
    number = thisName.split('[')[1].split(']')[0];
  alert(number);
});
```

it will work on all future inputs that will be placed within div element within body.

Comment: Thanks for this as well! A really good answer this too!